# How to display an image with mplayer?

Tags: mplayer, mencoder

**How can I display a `jpg` image with `mplayer` for an infinite amount of time?**

Wen opening an image with `mplayer`, the image is displayed for about 0.1s and then `mplayer` is leaving:

```
mplayer image.png
```

PS: the ultimate goal is to send a picture to /dev/fb0 which can be done with the mplayer option `-fbdev2 /dev/fb0`

Comment: The title mentions `ffmpeg` but you are only dealing with `mplayer`.

Answer (score 1):

`mplayer -nosound "mf://image.jpg" -mf type=jpg -loop 0`
or
`mplayer -nosound "mf://image.png" -mf type=png -loop 0`

These commands "play" an image repeatedly until mplayer is stopped, say, by hitting escape.